# Statistical methods to measure effectiveness of communication channels

Tags: machine-learning, multiarmed-bandit

Does anyone know of any techniques to measure the effectiveness of marketing calls/messages/mails basically any sort of communication channel used?

In general you can have several statuses for a person like he was reached out and the message was delivered but still the customer did not take it implying that customer's not taking the product was not an ideal indicator of the effectiveness of communication channel.

Also, are there any proxy variables for understanding customer's preference for mode of communication?

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to do sampling for your experiment group and control group. Then implement the experiment - in your case, marketing calls, mails, etc. Next comes the measurement phase. Look at incremental sales (or another target metric for your marketing campaign), lift in the metric and whether the particular lift is significant or not using significance testing methods. Hope this helps.